# std::variant<std::string_view, std::string> result_message;

Tags: c++, exception

I have a json-response from a web server containing several known "response codes".
For those, I have `constexpr` return codes which can be returned by `std::string_view`.
I want to prevent the copy there.
But I have also one (can be extended later) response string, which have to be generated, in a case, where the message can't be parsed or another error occurs.

Now I have 3 solutions I thought about, but I don't know which is conceptually the best.

1. Return a `std::variant<std::string_view, std::string>`
2. Throw an exception for the unlikely case, that a std::string has to be generated.
3. Create a static thread_local std::string, storing the last error and return a string_view.

I don't like any version:

3: Prone to dangling references, since the buffer of string can change.
2: Does not scale well, in the case, that a normal generated response will be added.
1: Extra indirection on each access. Increases code size and complexity.

What do you think?

Comment: Well, the YAGNI solution is to return a `std::string` until your profiler tells you to stop doing that.

Comment: I think Sneftel's solution is probably the quickest but if the response codes are known then perhaps an `enum class` representation is a better choice, you can just return a small struct with a string and an enum and just check the enum first. I wouldn't even bother with an optional because it won't save space really vs an empty string in the known response case.